# JavaScript override only specified options from a list of default options belonging to an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to create an object that has default options it resorts to unless certain options are specified by the user. The user can define any of the optional values as an array in any order and the values that haven't been defined by the user will instead take on the values defined in **defaultOptions** array.

In this case, the user wants to override the width and height of a Chart object only, while all the other **defaultOptions** will remain as defined in the class.

From my example, it doesn't seem to change the width and height to the user specified values, but instead uses the **defaultOptions** values.

```
class Chart {
```

```
constructor(div, data, options = {}) {

    let defaultOptions = {
        mode: "bar-chart",
        width: div.clientWidth,
        height: div.clientHeight,
        margin: {
            top: 10,
            right: 10,
            bottom: 10,
            left: 10
        },
        name: "Default Chart"
    }

    this.options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options);
}
```

}

/* create Chart object */
/* should override defaultOptions array width and height with these new values */
let chart = new Chart(div,{
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
});

/* alternatively, could create a Chart object with only mode value change */
let chart = new Chart(div,{
    mode: "pie-chart"
});

The answer should use vanilla Javascript, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem, and one thing to watch out for:

1. Your parameters are misaligned. You are sending your `options` as `data`. See below for an added `data` parameters when constructing.
2. Watch out for the nested objects if you want the caller to be able to apply individual margin properties. See below for one example of how to allow overriding only one margin property and keeping the others as default.

```js
class Chart {
  constructor(div, data, options = {}) {

    let defaultOptions = {
        mode: "bar-chart",
        width: div.clientWidth,
        height: div.clientHeight,
        margin: {
            top: 10,
            right: 10,
            bottom: 10,
            left: 10
        },
        name: "Default Chart"
    }

    this.options = Object.assign(
      {},
      defaultOptions,
      options,
      {margin: Object.assign(
        defaultOptions.margin,
        options.margin || {}
      )}
    );
  }
}



/* create Chart object /
/ should override defaultOptions array width and height with these new values */
let chart1 = new Chart(div1, {}, {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
});

/* alternatively, could create a Chart object with only mode value change */
let chart2 = new Chart(div2, {}, {
    mode: "pie-chart",
    margin: {bottom: 7},
});

console.log(chart1, chart2);
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="width: 317px; height: 321px; background-color: blue;">

<div id="div2" style="width: 172px; height: 251px; background-color: green;">
```